# SignalR not set up correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr-hub

Quite obviously, I am screwing something up, but it seems like I've followed the documentation properly, so I'm asking for some insights.

I have built a simple ASP.NET MVC5 application, and I am testing asynchronous notification of a file state.  As a proof of concept I:

- Installed SignalR from NuGet
- Added the script reference to my Layouts page
- Added the "script" reference to "~/signalr/hubs"

I created a new NotificationHub like so:

```
public class Notification
{
    public MessageLevels Type { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public enum MessageLevels
{
    Success,
    Info,
    Notice,
    Error
}
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public void Notify(Notification model)
    {
        Clients.Caller.notify(model);
    }
}
```

After this, I added the following notifications script to my Layouts page:

```
$(function() {
    var messages = $.connection.notificationHub;
    messages.client.notify = function(model) {
        $.pnotify({
            title: model.title,
            text: model.message,
            type: model.type
        });
    };
});
```

In my controller, I have something like this to test out the notification:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => SendNotification());
        return View();
    }

    private void SendNotification()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3500);
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

        context.Clients.All
        .Notify(new Notification
        {
            Message = "This is a test.",
            Title = "Test Message",
            Type = MessageLevels.Notice
        });
    }
```

When I run this, I am monitoring the following line in my web browser:

```
    $.pnotify({
```

... however, my breakpoint is never reached.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Per halter73's answer, I changed my script to this:

```
    $(function() {
        var connection = $.hubConnection();
        var notificationHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('notificationHub');
        notificationHubProxy.on('notify', function(model) {
            $.pnotify({
                title: model.title,
                text: model.message,
                type: model.type
            });
        });

        connection.start()
            .done(function() { console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
            .fail(function() { console.log('Could not connect'); });
    });
```

...and the breakpoint is now being reached.  However, all my vars are coming back as undefined... I'll have to play with that.  I expect it has something to do with my capitalization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is your call to `$.connection.hub.start()`? Is this called after you define  `$.connection.notificationHub.client.notify`?

If you do not define your client `notify` callback before you start the connection, you will not be subscribed to the `NotificationHub`. This could be why your `notify` callback containing your call to `$.pnotify` is never invoked.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection

Comment: Hmm... that is definitely different from the documentation I was looking at.